# How to get date from photos AND videos taken from UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

If you present a `UIImagePickerController` with a source type of `.Camera` (Swift), how can you get the date taken (or started recording, as in the case of a video) of the image or video in the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to access the `info` and extract the meta data and extract the date from that:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(nonnull UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info {
    NSString* meta = [[[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata] objectForKey:@"{TIFF}"] objectForKey:@"DateTime"];
    NSDateFormatter *form = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    form.dateFormat = @"yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss";
    NSDate* date = [form dateFromString:meta];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:^{}];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `imagePickerController(_picker, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info)` method of the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` protocol.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
      let metaDataDict = info.valueForKey(UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata) as? NSDictionary
      // print metaDataDict to see it's keys and values
      println("meta data = \(metaDataDict.description)")
}
```

You can then determine the key for the date the photo was taken (note that `[UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata][1]` is only for photos).

Answer (score 0):

First you present you `UIImagePickerController` and when you get the callback 
`imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)` grab the info dictionary and extract the date info:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    if let url = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL { // Its possible that there will not be a date present
    let assetsLibrary = ALAssetsLibrary()
    assetsLibrary.assetForURL(url, resultBlock: { (asset: ALAsset!) -> Void in
        if let date = asset.valueForProperty(ALAssetPropertyDate) as? NSDate {
            print("\(date)\n")
        }

        }) { (error: NSError!) -> Void in
            // Handle error
        }
    }
}
```

Be sure to link with `AssetsLibrary`.

Presenting can be done like so:

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
picker.delegate = self
self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I have used a source type of `.Camera`, not `.PhotoLibrary`.

Comment: Well sure, it will still work. But if you have just taken a photo you know the date already since it just got taken. Or does it need to be very precise?

Comment: Well, the thing is, when the you take a photo or a video, the image picker shows a view where you get to verify the photo or video you've taken. And if the user stays a significant amount of time on that view, the location will not be accurate.

Comment: I tried the code you wrote, but the program crashed because the `asset` argument of `resultBlock` of `assetForURL` is nil.